# Unsupported command in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I have Jenkins, it is deployed on a remote Windows machine and it connects via ssh to a remote Linux server. In Jenkins settings, in the “Exec command” section, I write simple commands for the test:

```
ls –lah 
pwd 
hostname
```

But in Jenkins console, I get a response like this:

```
SSH: ls [-lah] 
SSH: Failed command: [ls] 
SSH: FAILED: Message [No such file] 
SSH: Unsupported command [pwd] 
SSH: Unsupported command [hostname]
```

Does anyone know why these errors are? And how can these commands be executed through Jenkins?

Comment: Try "/bin/is" ...or "env" to see what your PATH is.

Comment: Where do these commands need to be entered? In "Exec command" Jenkins?

Comment: Yes, /bin/is instead of just ls, or replace ls with env to see your PATH, etc.

Comment: I entered these commands but this "Unsupported command" error appeared again.